# Magento 2: Image in custom email module?

Tags: magento2, email

I have created a custom module email template, but I am **unable to load the images** in `custom.html` file for email templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a static block insert images in that block and call it in respected custom.html files

> {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" area='frontend'
>   block_id="my_block"}}

Comment: Good to know you solved.

Comment: How to include this block to my custom module this block create automatically when my module loads

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to include the block. For example:

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html**

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Or, We can pass the data to the email template. For example:

**vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html**

```
                     <img
                            {{if logo_width}}
                                width="{{var logo_width}}"
                            {{else}}
                                width="180"
                            {{/if}}

                            {{if logo_height}}
                                height="{{var logo_height}}"
                            {{else}}
                                height="52"
                            {{/if}}

                            src="{{var logo_url}}"
                            alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                            border="0"
                        />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply where I have to place the images and call it in custom.html file

Comment: Check my code and let me know.

Comment: thanks khoa iam installed one custom module for email load at admin emails but unable call the images infooter section from pub media

Comment: you given a logo urls

Comment: I only give you a sample. You need to build your own. I think it's better if you use the first solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first solution you can get the image. It's a phtml template of Magento 2.

Comment: is there any code to directly call image in .html files

Comment: Let me check. Currently, you can try the easiest way I suggested.

Comment: ok I will try and get back to you

Comment: I have fixed it by trying as above answer please find my answer.